# libgit2 returned: Failed to create locked file. The system can not find the path specified

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I just setup GIT and installed tortoise git on my machine and able to clone through the client and after making changes inn the code, now I wanted to commit some code.

[image]

Now, when I enter name and email, then I get the below error.

[image]

I am still facing this issue and below solution not working this time.

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ANT_HOME=C:\Softwares\WSO2_AM\WSO2\API Manager\2.6.0
APPDATA=C:\Users\e081155\AppData\Roaming
CARBON_HOME=C:\Softwares\WSO2_AM\WSO2\API Manager\2.6.0
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=841DTN2
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DEFLOGDIR=C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 docker ps
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
HOME=C:\Users\e081155
HOMEDRIVE=H:
HOMEPATH=\
HOMESHARE=\\corp.abc.org\pune\Users\john
JAVA_HOME=C:\Softwares\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\john\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\PUN3DC12
M2=C:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin 
M2_HOME=C:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.5.4
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OS=Windows_NT
PATH=C:\SOFTWARES\JAVA\JDK1.8.0_171\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\PROGRAM FILES\DMEXPRESS\PROGRAMS;C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\CLIENT_1\BIN;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENSSH\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\PLANTRONICS\SPOKES3G\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\GIT\CMD;C:\SOFTWARES\APACHE-MAVEN-3.5.4\BIN;C:\USERS\E081155\APPDATA\ROAMING\NPM;C:\SOFTWARES\APACHE-ANT-1.10.5\BIN;C:\Softwares\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.3\bin;C:\Apache-Kafka\zookeeper-3.4.12\bin;C:\Program Files\cURL\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;%HOME%;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common\;C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Cloud Foundry;C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e09
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temp
TNS_ADMIN=C:\Softwares
UATDATA=C:\WINDOWS\CCM\UATData\D9F8C395-CAB8-491d-B8AC-179A1FE1BE77
USERDNSDOMAIN=CORP.ABC.ORG
USERDOMAIN=ABC
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=ABC
USERNAME=john
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\john
VSEDEFLOGDIR=C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection
windir=C:\WINDOWS
ZOOKEEPER_HOME=C:\Apache-Kafka\zookeeper-3.4.12
LC_ALL=C
GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin
SVN_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin
DISPLAY=:9999
SSH_ASKPASS=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe
GIT_ASKPASS=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe
GIT_ASK_YESNO=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe
```

Comment: There are some open questions: Which version of TortoiseGit? Is the environment variable `%HOME%` set? Where is your Windows profile located (also, what are the values of the environment variables `HOMEPATH` and `HOMEDRIVE`)?

Comment: @MrTux - Sorry for late reply. I am getting same error and unable to solve using  below suggestion. Could you please guide me ?

Comment: You are aware that 1.8.16 is a really old version? You should upgrade!

Comment: @MrTux - I have upgraded to 2.8.0, still facing the same error. Could you please guide ?

Comment: Why is %HOME% pointing to "C"? Have you set it manually? Does git.exe also complain resp. use you user settings? -> Removing or adjusting it to "H:\" should solve the issue (I'm going to add an answer if I have an answer to my first two questions).

Comment: Do you have any idea why %HOMEDRIVE% points to H and differs from %USERPROFILE%?

Comment: Could you please provide an excerpt of the reuqetsed environment variables from TortoiseGit Settings -> General -> Show Environment variables?

Comment: @MrTux - Yes `HOMEDRIVE=H:` and details has been updated

Comment: @MrTux - I am not too sure why %HOMEDRIVE% points to H and differs from %USERPROFILE%? It must be Org standards. Is there any way to override it ?

Comment: Do you know why %HOME% is set? Actually, setting %HOME% to %USERPROFILE% should fix the issue - doesn't it?